# Check whether an entry present in python list and add the elements

Tags: python, list

I have two python list of the form

```
list1 = [('TGFB1', 'TGFB1', 1), ('TGFB1', 'CRP', 0.4),('BRCA2', 'TP53', 0.3)]
list2 = [('BRCA1', 'TP53', 2), ('TGFB1', 'CRP', 0.4),('BRCA2', 'TP53', 0.3)]
```

I need to check whether each entry in list2 is present in list1 . If present add the integer part and store in a new list. If not present just append that entry to the newly created list. So here my newly created list3 should look like

```
list3 = [('TGFB1', 'TGFB1', 1), ('TGFB1', 'CRP', 0.8),('BRCA2', 'TP53', 0.6),('BRCA1', 'TP53', 2) ]
```

Comment: And by 'present' you mean the first two elements match?

Comment: *I need to check whether each entry in list2 is present in list1* here `if all(x in list2 for x in list1)`

Comment: You are using a poor data structure for what you want to achive. You definitely need a `dict` here where keys are tuples like `('TGFB1', 'TGFB1')` and values are the numbers. Then you could implement what you need in a single scan

Comment: @user85544, do the float/integer parts have to match also or just the first two elements as Martjin Pieters asked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following my above comment, this is what you might want:

```
from copy import copy

d3 = copy(dict(((x, y), z) for x, y, z in list1))
d2 = dict(((x, y), z) for x, y, z in list2)

for key, value in d2.iteritems():
    d3[key] = (d3[key] if key in d3 else 0.0) + value
```

If you do really want to turn `d3` then back to a list of the same structure use:

```
list3 = [key + (value,) for key, value in d3.iteritems()]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more complicated version of something that I often do. Usually, I don't care about order and just throw stuff into a dict. Or sometimes I order by key so the initial order doesn't matter.

How about an OrderedDict (python2.7+):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

list1 = [('TGFB1', 'TGFB1', 1), ('TGFB1', 'CRP', 0.4),('BRCA2', 'TP53',0.3)]
list2 = [('BRCA1', 'TP53',2), ('TGFB1', 'CRP', 0.4),('BRCA2', 'TP53',0.3)]

d=OrderedDict()
for i in list1:
    d[i[0:2]]=i[2]
for i in list2:
    if i[0:2] in d:
        d[i[0:2]]+=i[2]
    else:
        d[i[0:2]]=i[2]
list3=[k+(v,) for k,v in d.items()]
print(list3)
```